# PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "NULL"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata

I have this method in AssignmentTypeAdmin:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('code', 'text')
            ->add('label', 'text', array('label'=>'Libellé'))
            ->add('assignHierarchyNode.label', 'text', array('label' => 'Noeud hiérarchique'))
            ->add('assignPortfolioType.portfolioTypeLabel', null, array('label' => 'Type de portefeuille'))
            ->add('assignGeoHierarchyNodeType.label', null, array('label' => 'Type de noeud hiérarchique'));
    }
```

In AssignmentType class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="HierarchyManagerBundle\Entity\HierarchyNode")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="assign_hierarchy_node_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
 */
private $assignHierarchyNode;
```

In HierarchyNode class:
...

```
 /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\TreePathSource
     * @ORM\Column(name="label", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $label;
```

...
also get and set methods.

My problem is I get this error and I don't have any idea why:

*PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "NULL" while trying to traverse path "assignHierarchyNode.label" at property "label".*

I use Symfony 3.1, Doctrine 2.5.2, Sonata Bundle for this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is working your _constructor ? In your DB the id of the linked table is register ?

Comment: @Jeremy you are awesome! That is it! The __constructor it was not ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a look there : [Sonata PostPersist](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/saving_hooks.html)

Here you can find a Sonata constructor, it may help you. It can be better than using a _constructor. You can find just bellow an exemple.

```
public function postPersist($client)
{
    $em = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    if ($client instanceof Client )
    {
        $test = new Test();
        $test->setClient($client);
        $test->setSurname($client->getSurname());
        $test->setFirstname($client->getFirstname());
        $em->persist($test);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Hope it was usefull. If you have any question just ask.

Comment: Thank you! It was usefull your example.

Comment: If you got your answer you can save this post as solved. As if that someone is looking for an answer for a similar problem he will know he can find an answer to his question here.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it worked when i initialized it as an **array** or **ArrayCollection**.

```
public function __construct() {
   $this->conditions = [];
}
```

Symfony throws the exception because, if not initialized, it cannot iterate on it.